# Google's Blogger platform does not display </> or &lt;/&gt; ! How to fix?

Tags: html, blogger, html-entities

I want to insert a simple

```
&lt;/&gt;
```

on my blogger template.

The reason why I want to do it is use it as a logo of some kind for my blogger website.

I tried Chrome dev tools and inserted encoded HTML for </> and it worked. But when I do the same on blogger template, it doesn't show up.

Comment: `&lt;/&gt;` should show as `</>`, if you actually want the ampersands, do `&amp;lt;/&amp;gt;`

Comment: @Pamblam that worked. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Because you insert these character as **text** instead as **HTML code**.
Right click on entry tag in Chrome Developer Tools -> Elements and select **Edit as HTML** then insert these characters and enjoy.